# When will the iOS app get the update?

Tags: feature-request, support, stack-overflow, stack-exchange, ios-app

It's been a long time using an **unmaintained** iOS app. Does anybody know when will we (for example all iPhone X users) get **the** update?

Comment: TL;DR: never...